# How to copy and rename

Tags: batch-file, rename

I want to rename file by adding `"New_"` (variable text) before the orignal file name in the copying file.

Example : File `"Expenses_2013"` from `"C:\Users\Niki\Desktop\report"` copy to `"TargetFolder"` and rename as `"NEW_Expenses_2013"`.
File name `"Expenses_2013"` is not static..it's variable.  I have below command for this. I want to edit this command.

```
call :CopyandRename "C:\Users\Niki\Desktop\report" "%TargetFolder%\"
```

**NEW EDIT**

```
@echo off
setlocal
Set TargetFolder=C:\Users\Niki\Desktop\Final Report
call :copyAndRename "C:\Users\Niki\Desktop\Report" "%Targetfolder%\"

:: Done
goto :eof

:copyAndRename
set SourceFolder=%~1
set TargetFile=%~2

:: Find the newest file in the source folder
for /f "tokens=*" %%F in ('dir /b /od /a-d "%SourceFolder%"') do set "NewestFile=%%F"

:: copy and rename it to the target
copy "%SourceFolder%\%NewestFile%" "%TargetFile%"
pause

:: Done with this subroutine
goto :eof
```

Comment: There is no file name given after in the source "C:\Users\Niki\Desktop\Report" after report folder

Answer (score 3):

```
copy "C:\Users\Niki\Desktop\report\Expenses_2013" "%targetfolder%\New_Expenses_2013"
```

or more generally:

```
copy "%sourcefolder%\%sourcefile%" "%targetfolder%\New_%sourcefile%"
```

Comment: Endro..your answer is good one..but I can not apply in my script..please see above my full script. call :CopyandRename command is working as per script below that.

Comment: whatever is file in report folder will copy to target and should add "final_" at the begning of the file name. I cant not fix the file name in the report folder.b'z this not for just on source folder, I have lots more.

Comment: There is no file name given after in the source "C:\Users\Niki\Desktop\Report" after report folder

Comment: I just want to add "New_" in the file name without replacing characters of the file. And I want to do with above script by some edits.

Comment: so do **not** use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17185625/2098699) suggestion, try mine :)

Comment: your first Ans. will not work for me..b'z the file name is not static ..as per script whichever file is new at source it'll copy to target with orignal name.

Comment: and second Ans. will not call newest file concept which is sited below of the script.

Comment: if you enhance your quests. always more and more and never accept an answer after days and days of service nobody will post something for you:-) LP

Comment: Hay Endoro...sorry for this...I have enhance b'z make more clear..What I have and what I need...I thought I'll get an answer with my previous question...but those were not enough for my script.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Copy the files
In the command prompt, type:

```
COPY "C:\Users\Niki\Desktop\report\*" "%TargetFolder%\*"
```

Step 2: Rename
Type:

```
REN * NEW_*
```

Comment: Your ren command is wrong: it will replace 4 characters at the start of the line with NEW_ and not add it to the start of each filename.

Comment: @foxdrive, could you please check?

Comment: the rename command replaces the first letters from the file name simply with "NEW_". Look here: [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](http://superuser.com/questions/475874/how-does-the-windows-rename-command-interpret-wildcards).

Comment: That is I don't want..characters of file name should not be replaced. I wants to add "New_" in the file name.

Comment: Hi Rishi, I need your help..I can't explaned my needs here I want's to talk to you can I have your contact infos...please I am niki from Bangalore. Thx a lot for the help.

Comment: I would recommend you to post it on SO. Still if you need, my email id is on my profile

Comment: Above is the my new question regarding VB codes..plz have a look and let me know if you need more infos..